# Login con autentificación token

Tags: java, jwt, spring-security

Para un proyecto me han pedido realizar un login con autentificación token.
Como me recomendaron incluyo el codigo directamente.

Clase `SecurityConfig`:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //permitimos el acceso a /login a cualquiera
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
            .and() // Las peticiones /login pasaran previamente por este filtro
            .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) // Las demás peticiones pasarán por este filtro para validar el token
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Creamos una cuenta de usuario por default
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("ask")
            .password("123")
            .roles("ADMIN");
     }
}
```

Clase `LoginFilter` por donde deberian de pasar las peticiones /login

```
 public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public LoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        // obtenemos el body de la peticion que asumimos viene en formato JSON
        InputStream body = req.getInputStream();

        // Asumimos que el body tendrá el siguiente JSON  {"username":"ask", "password":"123"}
        // Realizamos un mapeo a nuestra clase User para tener ahi los datos
        User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, User.class);

        // Finalmente autenticamos
        // Spring comparará el user/password recibidos
        // contra el que definimos en la clase SecurityConfig
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                 user.getUsername(),
                 user.getPassword(),
                 Collections.emptyList()
            )
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Si la autenticacion fue exitosa, agregamos el token a la respuesta
        JwtUtil.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

Clase `User`:

```
class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

y este es el error que me sale en el eclipse cuando entro a `localhost:8080/login`

> ```
> 2017-09-04 00:16:54.555 ERROR 9920 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
>   at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@da63d5a; line: 1, column: 0]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3854) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2924) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>   at com.example.config.LoginFilter.attemptAuthentication(LoginFilter.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
> ```

Para mi es nuevo esto de la autentificacion por token, por lo que he seguido el siguiente tutorial: https://windoctor7.github.io/spring-jwt.html  donde se implementa, pero no he podido ejecutar el proyecto .

Si alguien sabe una forma de resolverlo o conoce otra forma de poder implementarlo seria de gran ayuda, muchas gracias.
https://github.com/yisus2017/Login-Token

Comment: Hola J.Edu, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [ask] para encontrar consejos sobre cómo mejorar tu pregunta y que sea más fácil ayudarte. Por ejemplo, sería bueno que incluyeras el código directamente en la pregunta en lugar de enlazado en un sitio externo (los enlaces se rompen y entonces la publicación deja de tener sentido); además, si no se ejecuta el proyecto, sería de ayuda que incluyeras los mensajes de error que recibas en el log.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se ve en la `exception` que te devuelve. Te esta fallando cuando realiza el mapeo a la clase `User`.

```
User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, User.class);
```

Fíjate realmente que estas mandando en el `Body` de la llamada. Según el ejemplo debería ser algo de este estilo

```
{
 "username":"ask",
 "password":"123" 
}
```

Espero que mi comentario te sea de ayuda.